# I want to update series of UI,when data change?Is there a good way?

Tags: android

**I want to update series of UI,when data change?Is there a good way?**

I changed some data in an activity, then I need to update three different fragments. I have tried two ways:

1. use EventBus
2. use BroadCast to notify

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you call some public methods from fragments directly from the activity? You can take instances of your fragments from the FragmentManager by calling findFragmentById with ids that you specified before and just call some method. It's the simplest way to update anything in the fragments.

Comment: @Peregreen leads to `NullPointerException` if fragment is not loaaded. so he needs to check fragment is showing or not

Comment: @AbhishekSingh yes, of course, the fragments should be added first, it's well described in the description of the method itself:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)

Comment: @Peregreen sorry, I forget to say that Fragments are in PageAdapter, I have tried to use public methods , but I do think its heavy.

Comment: @ngU If you use FragmentPagerAdapter/FragmentStatePagerAdapter, then you passing some FragmentManager there and this adapter works over it. It means you can access your fragments through this manager.